# Why am I getting different output from the Matcher tutorial on different PCs?

Tags: spacy

I am working through the tutorial exercises on the Spacy website. I have completed the exercise for the Matcher and the tutorial website returns the expected output. When I paste the code into a Jupyter notebook on my work laptop I also get the expected output, but when I run the code on my home PC I get something else.

```
import spacy

# Import the Matcher
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("New iPhone X release date leaked as Apple reveals pre-orders by mistake")

# Initialize the Matcher with the shared vocabulary
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

# Create a pattern matching two tokens: "iPhone" and "X"
pattern = [{'TEXT': 'iPhone'}, {'TEXT': 'X'}]

# Add the pattern to the matcher
matcher.add("IPHONE_X_PATTERN", None, pattern)

# Use the matcher on the doc
matches = matcher(doc)
print("Matches:", [doc[start:end].text for match_id, start, end in matches])
```

The expected results are:

```
Matches: ['iPhone X']
```

But the output on my home machine is:

```
Matches: ['New', 'iPhone', 'X', 'release', 'date', 'leaked', 'as', 'Apple', 'reveals', 'pre', '-', 'orders', 'by', 'mistake']
```

confirmed by `len(matches)` returning `14`.

I guess there's something different about my setup at home, but can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a different version of the `en_core_web_sm` model?

Can you run `python -m spacy validate` and compare the output on the different systems?

Comment: Alternatively, it could also be a different version of spaCy. The example uses the `TEXT` key, which was only introduced in v2.1.

Comment: Thanks both. My spaCy version is 2.0.16. I will update and see if that fixes it. In the meantime, I have rerun the code with `ORTH` instead of `TEXT` and got the right output.